# Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема

Tags: c#

Имеется два .cs файла, которые должны между собой взаимодействовать, но происходит это как-то странно. Мне нужно вызвать функцию MainAction, которая находится в Class1, из Class2.
Различными способами у меня максимум получалось сделать это два раза, а далее программа просто стояла на месте. В чём ошибка, ткните носом пожалуйста

Class1.cs

```
public partial class Class1 : MetroForm
{ 
    public Confirm()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       backgroundoworker1.DoWork += fornewthread;
    }
    public void Action1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (backgroundworker1.IsBusy != true)
           {
             backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
           }
       else 
           {
           MessageBox.Show("Error! Worker is busy.");
           }
    }
    public void MainAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //тут происходит много действий
        }
}
```

Class2.cs

```
private void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (var1 >= var2)
        {
            //здесь пробовал и такое:
            Class1.action1(sender, e);
            This.Close();
            //и такое:
            Class1.MainAction(sender, e);
            This.Close();
        }
}
```

Но ни один из этих вариантов не помог.

Comment: Это вы привели _полное_ содержимое файла Class2.cs? Как у вас оно вообще скомпилировалось?

Comment: @VladD Конечно нет, не полное. Проблема ещё в том, что мне нужен некий "цикл", а именно чтобы выполнились действия в MainAction, далее несколько действий из Class2 и опять вернуться в MainAction и так далее. Кодом, который указан сверху, этот цикл выполняется почему-то только два раза, а далее программа стоит.

Comment: Ну так приведите компилируемый кусок, а то пока не очень понятно, что у вас там происходит и кто кого вызывает.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы обратиться к методу `Action1` нужно создать экземпляр класса, т.к. метод не статический:

```
var instance = new Class1();
instance.Action1(sender, e);
```

Или же сделайте метод статическим:

```
public static void Action1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Остальной код
}
```

Тогда вы сможете вызывать метод без создания экземпляра.